# Juniper MX-5 EOPE Drop Pkt Cnt Incrementing

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-mx, errors

When running `show pfe statistics error` on a a couple of MX platforms, I see the `EOPE Drop Pkt Cnt` counter incrementing on 6 MX's out of 22. I believe these are "End-Of-Packet errors", but can't find any details about it at all.

Any ideas? If not, I'll log a JTAC case.

[image: show pfe statistics error]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to provide an answer for anyone else experiencing similar issues, this was a cosmetic bug that was fixed from JUNOS 12.3 onwards.

Actual update from TAC

> "There is an issue with the stats collection command where the HW counter was not getting cleared. Thus the stats reporting was continuously incrementing it's counter even though no actual EOPE errors were occurring.
>
> This is a cosmetic issue and doesn't have any impact on the production traffic.
>
> Junos 11.4 is an Extended End of Life release. The next release for JUNOS 11.4 is 11.4R12. 
>   If your customer wishes I can open a scope for it and the fix to go in to the following releases: 12.3R7 13.2R5 13.3R3 14.1R1.

Comment: Excellent outcome, thanks for following up with a solution.